# Toilet flush button is corroded and gets stuck

Tags: plumbing, toilet, corrosion

[image: Button naturally gets stuck like this after depressing it][image: Corroded button]

My toilet flushing button gets stuck with one button extended. It doesn’t affect the toilets flushing but it is a little ugly. I’m very new to DIY so I’m not sure if I can just scrub the blue stuff (which I presume is corroded metal?) off and then put the button back in place. Or would that just mean the button would get even more corroded.

Thanks

Comment: try soaking the metal in Coke ... the phosphoric acid in Coke may dissolve the corrosion

Comment: You could probably soak the whole thing in [CLR](https://www.amazon.com/CLR-Calcium-Remover-Enhanced-Formula/dp/B00009EFEX) and brush it about 2-3 rounds or find a replacement for your specific model if that's easier.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to like pure silicone grease for articulating plumbing parts. I keep a jar of food grade silicone grease in the shop. Its usually sold in scuba gear shops, but I see it gaining popularity for other applications.

I'd clean the toilet flush button parts with something like CLR, lube with silicone grease and reassemble. Besides lubricating, the grease should help keep air and water off of the brass to slow down the corrosion. But it's probably time to start looking for some replacement parts.